# Why won't VS let me use var in CSS

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I am trying to use the var syntax for different colors on my website. However it doesn't show the color and makes me use rgb to make colors appear.What am I doing wrong.Also I am using Visual Studio code

```
:root {
  --primaryColor: #f09d51;
  --mainWhite: #fff;
  --mainBlack: #222;
  --mainGrey: #ececec;
  --mainSpacing: 0.1rem;
  --mainTransition: all 0.3s linear;
}


.cart-items {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  background: #f09d51;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 30%;
  color: var(--mainWhite);
}
```

[Picture of the cart using rgb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs6rx.png)

[Picture of the cart using var](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrNAC.png)

Comment: :root instead of root

Comment: That's just a typo I have root in my code

Comment: Update your version of VS? If it works on an actual page, it's not *really* an issue.

Comment: I'm bout to update now but only works when I use rgb. What if I have alot of colors, I would rather use var then to keep having to find colors and copying and pasting

Comment: The question is **does it actually work** on an actual page? If so, then you can safely ignore any VS issues.

Comment: Confused about your question because if it worked on an actual page I wouldn't have made the post. On live server the 0 doesn't have a orange background unless I use rgb.

Answer (score 0):

Alright found the answer. I guess explorer does not support var use. I used firefox and chrome to open it and everything worked out